# Typeahead js breaks bootstrap inline-form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I have this form:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline" name="frmUserData" id="frmUserData">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtlitm">Item Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtlitm" name="txtlitm" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtmcu">Branch Plant (filter):</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtmcu" name="txtmcu">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtlocn">Location (filter):</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtlocn" name='txtlocn'>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="pull-left btn btn-default" id="btnGO">
            Search
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

which looks like this right after i enable typeahead.js:

[PIC LINK](http://s27.postimg.org/438g3vrdf/Snap1.jpg)

[image: Screenshot]

Item Code label is not aligned with the textbox as the other fields.

What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

Typeahead.js sets "vertical-align:top" to the input element and that's causing your problem (see line 753 and line 758 in typeahead.bundle.js)

You can change it in the JS or override it through CSS:

```
.form-inline .form-control {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe set the column sizes will do the trick:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2">Item Code:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtlitm" name="txtlitm" autocomplete="off">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Branch Plant (filter):</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtmcu" name="txtmcu">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Location (filter):</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtlocn" name='txtlocn'>
        </div>
    </div>
```